# How do I adjust or disable bold text on jQuery UI Tabs?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have been messing around with this for two days but I can't seem to "decode" the extensive css used in jQuery UI.
I am using jQuery UI 1.13 tabs with the default stylesheet and what I would like to change about it is the bold text on hover. Both the active and inactive tabs display bold text when the mouse is over and normal weight when it's not..
I would like the active tab to have bold text all the time (regardless of mouse) and the inactive tabs to have normal text at all times (regardless of mouse).
I have looked at and tried the theme roller but it does not seem to include settings for bold text and hover.
I can see in the browser inspector that the list items append the class ui-state-hover on mouse over so I've tried things like:

```
.ui-state-hover a:hover {
   font-weight:normal;
}
```

Which gets half of the job done i.e. there is no bold text at all on or off hover. But I still have the requirement to make the active tab bold and when trying to do so, the code above will make it normal on mouse over.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks.

Edit: Added a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k74yo89b/
Theme: Smoothness

Comment: Could you please add a fiddle to your question? And which theme are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, playing with it in jsfiddle actually made it a lot easier. I seem to have found a solution in this simplified environment:

```
li.ui-state-active a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
li.ui-state-active a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```